# Get Intermediate layer output for ONNX mode

Tags: deep-learning, model, inference, onnx

I have an ONNX model and I want to debug the intermediate layer outputs and inputs of the model. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

ONNX currently does not support direct access to the model, but one can modify the model's graph by adding additional outputs. Here is an example for Python:

```py
import onnx
from onnx import helper

model = onnx.load("model.onnx")

# getting the first layer from the graph
intermediate_layer1 = helper.make_tensor_value_info(
    name='<name of the layer>',  # Name in the ONNX graph
    elem_type=onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, 
    shape=SHAPE  # Shape of the intermediate tensor
)
model.graph.output.append(intermediate_layer1)

# getting the second one
intermediate_layer2 = helper.make_tensor_value_info(
    name='<name of another layer>',  # Name in the ONNX graph
    elem_type=onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT, 
    shape=SHAPE  # Shape of the intermediate tensor
)
model.graph.output.append(intermediate_layer2)

onnx.save(model, "model_modified.onnx")
```

You can add an arbitrary number of outputs. The name and the shape of the target layer can be obtained from the ONNX graph by printing the model using Python or by uploading it to [netron.app](https://netron.app/).